# Cannot create inline Web Worker in Firefox 35 addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, web-worker

I'm developing a XUL based Firefox extension. I'm trying to create an inline Web Worker using BLOB. The code used to work in Firefox 33 but after update to Firefox 35 I get an error. Here is a code sample:

```
try {
    var blob = new Blob(["function f(){}"], {type: "application/javascript"});
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob); //blob:null/371e34bd-1fbf-4f66-89cc-24d0c1c7bad5
    return new Worker(url);
} catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
}
```

And I get a following error:

```
Failed to load script (nsresult = 0x805303f4)
```

I'm aware that this error appears when Web Worker tries to load a script from a different domain but I cannot figure out why this is happening in my case. The url I get from createObjectURL() function appears to be invalid. It contains "null/" prefix.

Does anybody have an explanation what is going on? What is the possible fix here?

Comment: It may be that `Blob` is no longer in the addon scope (i havent been able to use it in JSMs for a little while now), im not sure, try importing Blob like this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob#Chrome_Code_-_Scope_Availability also i see you're tapping into `window` to get `window.URL` you can import URL as well in same manner: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL#Chrome_Code_-_Scope_Availability

Comment: Where exactly do you run that code? In the XUL (chrome) scope, injected into the webpage, via a `SandBox`? Please provide a *full*, reproducible example.

Comment: The code is running in the chrome scope, it is NOT injected into any webpage. Adding `Components.utils.importGlobalProperties(['Blob', 'URL']);` doesn't help.

Comment: Seems you found a bug... that was fixed in later versions again. Can reproduce with Firefox 35, but Firefox 36 and Nightly work fine again.

Comment: @nmaier Should saloman file a bug at bugzilla so he can support FF35 for the next 3 months? As theres no work around to this huh?

Comment: @Noitidart Why three months? Firefox 36 is planned for Feb 24. Filing a bug might be helpful even tho the bug was fixed already. It might have been accidentally fixed, and telling mozilla about it might make them add a regression test so that this bug won't be accidentally reintroduced later. However, it is highly unlikely that there will be a FX35 maintenance release fixing it.

Comment: works just fine with mozilla nightly 38.0a1 (2015-01-27)

Comment: FF35 introduced a lot of bugs. Thankfully a lot have been fixed in 35.0.1 so give that a try before filing a bug.

Comment: Still reproducible in 35.0.1. Filled a bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1126217

Answer (score 1):

This example work for me, tested from Firefox 37 to 39.0a2.

```
// URL.createObjectURL
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

// "Server response", used in all examples
var response = "self.onmessage=function(e){postMessage('Worker: '+e.data);}";

var blob;
try {
    blob = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/javascript'});
} catch (e) { // Backwards-compatibility
    window.BlobBuilder = window.BlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.MozBlobBuilder;
    blob = new BlobBuilder();
    blob.append(response);
    blob = blob.getBlob();
}
var worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));

// Test, used in all examples:
worker.onmessage = function(e) {
    alert('Response: ' + e.data);
};
worker.postMessage('Test');
```